# Angularjs require controller from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that will be used in multiple places in the app and I want it to opt into a controller.

When using the controller method

```
return {
      ...
      controller: 'BlogDashCourseCtrl',
      ...
      }
```

it gets the controller fine. But when I require it

```
return {
      ...
      require: '^BlogDashCourseCtrl',
      ...
      link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs) {
          $scope.title = iAttrs.title; // Do not share me with other directives
          if($scope.title === $scope.step) { // $scope.step comes from a shared scope
              ...
          }
      }
}
```

it can't find the controller.

I don't want the controller to be called multiple times. I just want the directives to share a scope, have a private scope, too (so $scope in the directive doesn't bubble up) and do some stuff with a service.

Comment: That's not what the `require` parameter does. It does not mean it inherits that controller but that you get access to it (them) in the `link` function (`link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {`)

Comment: let me revise the question Sergui

Answer (score 0):

A directive is attached to a DOM node. A DOM node can't have two scopes. Either you share the parent scope or you create an isolated one and explicitly inherit stuff from it.

```
BlogDashCourseCtrl:
    this.step = 'whatever'; //maybe $scope.step


SomeDirective:
return {
      ...
      require: '^BlogDashCourseCtrl',
      ...
      link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, blogDashCourseCtrl) {
          $scope.title = iAttrs.title; // Do not share me with other directives
          if($scope.title === blogDashCourseCtrl.step) { // $scope.step comes from a shared scope
              ...
          }
      }
}
```

Notice that `blogDashCourseCtrl` does not reference the `$scope` of that directive/controller, but the reference itself.
There really is [extensive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate) on this, with examples.